# JavaScript Global Variable Not Updating Value

Tags: javascript, variables, post

I have the below JavaScript code to develop an app in Fuse Tools. There is one last error that I cannot seem to understand and that is that my variable b64data should be a global variable and is not updating it's value from the capturePhoto function and letting me send the updated value in the submitPhoto function to the server. It should send the base64 encoded value as the picture variable in my POST function. Any help is appreciated!

```
var Observable = require("FuseJS/Observable");
let ImageTools = require("FuseJS/ImageTools");
var FileSystem = require("FuseJS/FileSystem");
var Base64 = require("FuseJS/Base64");
var Camera = _camera;
var b64data;

var captureMode = Observable();
var flashMode = Observable();

function getCameraInfo() {
    Camera.getCameraInfo()
        .then(function(info) {
            console.log("captureMode: " + info[Camera.INFO_CAPTURE_MODE]);
            console.log("flashMode: " + info[Camera.INFO_FLASH_MODE]);
            console.log("cameraFacing: " + info[Camera.INFO_CAMERA_FACING]);
            console.log("supportedFlashModes: " + info[Camera.INFO_SUPPORTED_FLASH_MODES].join());

            captureMode.value = info[Camera.INFO_CAPTURE_MODE];
            flashMode.value = info[Camera.INFO_FLASH_MODE];

            if (Camera.INFO_PHOTO_RESOLUTIONS in info) {
                var availableResolutions = info[Camera.INFO_PHOTO_RESOLUTIONS];
                availableResolutions.forEach(function(e) {
                    console.log(e.width + "x" + e.height);
                });
                photoResolution = availableResolutions[Math.floor(availableResolutions.length * 0.4)];

                var options = {};
                options[Camera.OPTION_PHOTO_RESOLUTION] = photoResolution;

                Camera.setPhotoOptions(options)
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log("New photo options set: " + JSON.stringify(options));
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Failed to set photo options: " + error);
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Failed to get camera info: " + err);
        });
}
getCameraInfo();

function nextFlashMode() {
    if (flashMode.value == Camera.FLASH_MODE_AUTO) return Camera.FLASH_MODE_ON;
    else if (flashMode.value == Camera.FLASH_MODE_ON) return Camera.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
    else if (flashMode.value == Camera.FLASH_MODE_OFF) return Camera.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
    else throw "Invalid flash mode";
}

function setCaptureMode(cm) {
    Camera.setCaptureMode(cm)
        .then(function(mode) {
            captureMode.value = mode;
            console.log("Capture mode set to: " + mode);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Failed to set capture mode: " + err);
        });
}

function capturePhoto() {
    Camera.capturePhoto()
        .then(function (photo) {
            photo.save()
                .then(function(filePath) {
                    console.log("Photo saved to: " + filePath);
                    var arrayBuff = FileSystem.readBufferFromFileSync(filePath);
                    var b64data = Base64.encodeBuffer(arrayBuff); // send this to the backend
                    photo.release();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Failed to save photo: " + error);
                    photo.release();
                });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Failed to capture photo: " + error);
        });
}

var isRecording = Observable(false);
var recordingSession = null;

function startRecording() {
    isRecording.value = true;
    Camera.startRecording()
        .then(function (session) {
            recordingSession = session;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Failed to start recording: " + error);
            isRecording.value = false;
        });
}

function stopRecording() {
    isRecording.value = false;
    recordingSession.stop()
        .then(function (recording) {
            router.push("VideoPage", recording.filePath());
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Failed to stop recording: " + error);
        });
    recordingSession = null;
}

var cameraBack = true;
function flipCameraFacing() {
    var front = Camera.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    var back = Camera.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    Camera.setCameraFacing(cameraBack ? front : back)
        .then(function (newFacing) {
            cameraBack = newFacing == back;
            getCameraInfo();
            console.log("Camera facing set to: " + (newFacing == back ? "back" : "front"));
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Failed to set camera facing: " + err);
        });
}

function changeFlashMode() {
    Camera.setFlashMode(nextFlashMode())
        .then(function(newFlashMode) {
            flashMode.value = newFlashMode;
            console.log("Flash mode set to: " + flashMode.value);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Failed to set flash mode: " + err);
        });
}

var name = Observable();
var email = Observable();
var market = Observable();

module.exports = {
    name: name, 
    email: email,
    market: market,
    b64data: b64data,
    submitPhoto: submitPhoto,
    captureMode: captureMode,
    setCaptureModePhoto: function () { setCaptureMode(Camera.CAPTURE_MODE_PHOTO); },
    setCaptureModeVideo: function () { setCaptureMode(Camera.CAPTURE_MODE_VIDEO); },
    capturePhoto: capturePhoto,
    startRecording: startRecording,
    stopRecording: stopRecording,
    isRecording: isRecording,
    flipCameraFacing: flipCameraFacing,
    flashMode: flashMode,
    changeFlashMode: changeFlashMode,
}

function submitPhoto(){ 


    console.log("name: "+name);
    console.log("email: "+email);
    console.log("market: "+market);


    fetch('http://fanbeauties.com/app/submit-photo.php?pass=MY_PASS', { 
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: '&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&market='+market+'&picture='+b64data
     });


};
```

Comment: probably because you set it in a promise but don't wait until the promise is finished before you try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because of you are declaring `b64data` again in `capturePhoto` function on line 72 in your shared code.

try
`b64data = ...`
instead of 
`var b64data = ...`